# Similarity matrix using a spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For an input `Dataframe` the intent is to generate only half of the self-cartesian product. Given the cartesian product results in a symmetric matrix we only really need to calculate either the upper or the lower triangular portion above (resp below) the diagonal that is set to zeros:

The dataframe `crossjoin` :

```
val df3 = df2.crossJoin(df2)
```

will generate the ***FULL*** - which we do not want.

Given the similarity matrix is symmetric with 1's along the diagonal we do not need to calculate the upper half or the diagonal itself - as shown in the ***LOWER DiagO's*** below:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to obtain the result with the least computation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is not a perfect answer: it does result in first generating the full `cartesian` product. But at least the output results are correct.

```
/** Generate schema for cartesian product of an input dataframe */
def joinSchema(df: DataFrame) = 
  types.StructType(df.schema.fields.map {
    f => StructField(s"${f.name}_a", f.dataType, f.nullable)
  } ++ df.schema.fields.map { f => StructField(s"${f.name}_b", f.dataType, f.nullable)}
)

// Create the cartesian product via crossJoin
val schema = joinSchema(dfIn)
val df3 = df2.crossJoin(dfIn)
val cartesianDf = spark.createDataFrame(df3.rdd, schema)

cartDf.createOrReplaceTempView("cartesian")

// Retain the lower triangular entries below the diagonal
select * from cartesian where id_a < id_b
```